# Text box in a popup effecting a style for the controlling button

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup, datatrigger

I am trying to build a text filter for a list in a popup, and notify the user when the filter is active by changing the color of the button that opens the popup.

I am using an MVVM lite setup and a XAML style sheet to reference the desired styles. Up until this point I have created the popup and the controlling button, and I have been able to put a mouse over trigger on the button and have it work. However when I tried to have a  datatrigger set to the value of the textbox in the popup, it does not respond at all.

Here is the XAML code in the View for the button and the popup:

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Filter Popup" />
                <Button x:Name="PopUpControl" Tag="popup" Style="{StaticResource FilterButtonStyle}" Command="{Binding OpenPopupCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsFilterEnabled, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="2,1,2,1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Popup x:Name="textPopup" IsOpen="{Binding IsFilterPopupOpen, Mode=TwoWay}" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PopUpControl}" Placement="Bottom" Width="Auto" StaysOpen="False" Margin="2 2 2 2">
       <TextBox x:Name="TextValue" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="1" Style="{StaticResource WatermarkedTextBox}" Margin="2,4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Tag="Text Filter" Text="{Binding FilterSearch, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
                    <Button Grid.Column="4" Style="{StaticResource SearchIconStyle}" IsEnabled="{Binding FilterEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" Command="{Binding ApplyFilterCommand}" Margin="19,6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                </Grid>
            </Popup>
```

Here is the style for the button:

```
 <Style x:Key="SortButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="15"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="15"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4,0,4,0" />
    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="Default" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Name="border" 
                        Padding="4,2" 
                        CornerRadius="3" 
                        Background="{DynamicResource PaleBlue}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <Border.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_filter}" />
                    </Border.OpacityMask>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ColumnHeaderFilterColor}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

What I would like to happen, is when the element "TextValue" has a value in the Text field, the primary background color for the "border" changes color. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `DataTrigger` that binds to the `FilterSearch` source property and sets a property if returns an empty `string` or `null`:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
    <Border Name="border" 
            Padding="4,2"
            CornerRadius="3" 
            Background="Green">
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <Border.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_filter}" />
        </Border.OpacityMask>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FilterSearch}" Value="">
            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource PaleBlue}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FilterSearch}" Value="{x:null}">
            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource PaleBlue}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. i didnt even think to target the named variable for the textbox value. Thank you.